# MYSQL: should i use 2 tables for 2 types of user with common and different field?

Tags: mysql, database-design

i have 2 type of users
1. employee.
2. employees friend.

both users have common fields. 
1.first name 
2.middle name 
3.surname 
4.cellphone number
5.telephone number
6.city address 
7.email (serve as login)
8.password
9.registration date
10. update account date

and the employee friend user don't have this field 
1.employee id
2.company name.
3.company branch
4.position

and they will be going to use same login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think about this the same way I think about object oriented programming. If employee EXTENDS user then employee should be a user with extra information. I would have two tables.

`Users` (containing the common fields adding an id field perhaps)
&
`Employees` (with the 4 extra fields for employees and one field that references a unique identifier in the users table.)

More information about what I am proposing can be found here: http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MappingInheritance

Comment: thanks i got the idea, i separate the 4 fields that the employees_friend doesnt have and i made new table called employee_company_details. thanks

Answer (score 1):

edited version (thanks to nawfal and Patrick James McDougle)

1st table (user) should contain field 1-10(first list) and a new field fk_employees (foreign key to our 2nd table, *null* if it is an employees_friend)

2nd table (employees) should contain field 1-4(second list)

Comment: It's the other way around right? 2nd table should be about employees

Comment: thanks for the resposnse. 
why does employees_friend should contain the four fields that he/she will not place a data?

Comment: @nawfal: no, I don't think so. Every person exists in the **employee** table. If this person is a **employees_friend**, it has a foreign key to the **employees_friend** record.

Comment: @Luke94 employee_friend_user does NOT have those extra fields employee does. EVERYONE has the first 10 fields.

Comment: @Luke94 that's a wrong design. Why would employees_friend have another table when it actually has lesser number of columns?

Comment: @all: I'm so so sorry :-(. I have read it wrong twice. I will edit my answer to correct it.

Comment: @all yes thats a wrong design, so i come up to idea that the 4 other fields should i remove to employees table and create new one called employees_company_details so there are no blank field inside the employees table .

Answer (score 0):

what i suggest create 2 separate tables as users and user_friends with the fields mentioned above.

Now create a view with following query:

```
select employeeID,email,password from users
union
select friendID,email,password from user_friends
```

Query this view to get the login info in your application.